# Alamofire and SwiftyJSON with Carthage in Xcode6.3

Tags: ios, alamofire, swifty-json, carthage

I would really like to use Carthage to install Alamofire and SwiftJSON but I can't get it to work. It fails every single time to build.

Here is my Cartfile (point at the correct branches for Xcode 6.3):

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "xcode-6.3"
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" "xcode6.3"
```

Alamofire fails to build with these errors:

```
error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x7fbfb9e4d5d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2015-02-18 23:15:51.859 xcodebuild[53900:6388252] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'c'.
Compiler: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1
2015-02-18 23:15:51.865 xcodebuild[53900:6388253] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x7fbfbbb474d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2015-02-18 23:15:51.865 xcodebuild[53900:6388253] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'c'.
Compiler: /ur/bin/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /ur/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1
2015-02-18 23:15:52.448 xcodebuild[53900:6388249]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6269/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:77
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/devonboyer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alamofire-gpmlmgkqhnaqwsdibrprtyuyoqpu/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Alamofire iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Alamofire.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fbfb9e774f0 {NSFilePath=/Users/devonboyer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alamofire-gpmlmgkqhnaqwsdibrprtyuyoqpu/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Alamofire iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Alamofire.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbfb9e71f00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/devonboyer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alamofire-gpmlmgkqhnaqwsdibrprtyuyoqpu/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Alamofire iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Alamofire.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, void (^__strong)(NSString *__strong))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbfb9e1a3a0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/devonboyer/Desktop/Reach/Reach/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

SwiftyJSON fails to build with this error:

```
Scheme SwiftyJSONOSX is not currently configured for the build action.
```

I would really like to figure out why this doesn't work as I think Carthage could be really awesome. Note that I didn't do anything except follow the instructions on the Cartage git repo. Simply ran cartage update and this happened. Any ideas?

The xcode-select path is properly pointing to the beta version of Xcode

/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: Have you used `xcode-select` to pick the beta version of Xcode for command-line builds?

Comment: No I haven't how do I go about doing that. Maybe thats what is wrong...Thanks for the response btw!

Comment: See `xcode-select --help`. You want to use `--switch` to point it at the beta version of Xcode, so that the beta version of `xcodebuild` will be used on the command line by Carthage.

Comment: I was able to change the beta version with xcode-select but unfortunately it still failed to build with similar errors. The path is now /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: Do you have run `brew update` ?

Comment: Yeah I made sure I installed latest version of Carthage before trying anything else.

Comment: SwiftyJSON master does not build with Swift 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I decided to temporarily circumvent Carthage to get SwiftyJSON to build. I took the following steps (it looks more complicated than it is)

1.) Clone SwiftyJSON from github

2.) switch to xcode6.3 branch

3.) open SwiftyJSOn in Xcode 6.3 (non beta now)

4.) delete the debug configuration (to force it to build the release config)

5.) Select the SwiftyJSON project and open the right side bar and change the "Project Format" to Xcode 6.3 compatible

[image]

6.) Build The project

7.) Open DerivedData and navigate though until you find SwiftyJSON.framework

8.) Move SwiftyJSON.framework into your $(SRC_ROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/

9.) Your project should now be able to find SwiftyJSON

Good luck, and god speed